# Зачем нужны несколько тегов, если они делают одно и то же?

Tags: теги, html

В HTML есть теги выделения курсивом `<i>`, `<em>`, `<cite>`; выделения жирным шрифтом `<b>`, `<strong>`.  Зачем нужны несколько тегов если они делают то же самое. В чем их принципиальное отличие?

Answer (score 9):

теги **`<b>`** и **`<strong>`**, также как **`<i>`** и **`<em>`**, несмотря на сходный результат, не совсем эквивалентны и заменяемы. Первый тег **`<b>`** — относится к тегам физической разметки и устанавливает жирный текст, а тег **`<strong>`** — является тегом логической разметки и определяет важность помеченного текста. Такое разделение тегов на логическое и физическое форматирование изначально предназначалось, чтобы сделать HTML универсальным, в том числе не зависящим от устройства вывода информации. Теоретически, если воспользоваться, например, речевым браузером, то текст, оформленный с помощью тегов **`<b>`** и **`<strong>`**, будет отмечен по-разному. Однако получилось так, что в популярных браузерах результат использования этих тегов равнозначен.

Comment: Понятно. А что скажете насчет тега cite?. Он тоже делает текст курсивом

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/cite

Comment: Ну для чего нужен тег cite если он также выделяет курсивом, как и em?

Comment: Тег <cite> очень полезен для цитирования библиографий(обычно используеться для коротких цитат) и других ссылок сайта. Этот тег это строчным аналогом тега <blockquote>

Comment: Так в чем  полезность cite если он неотличается от тега em? И тот и другой просто выделяют текст курсивом и все.

Comment: @Maksim, теги различаются не только отображением. Это *сверху* только курсив видно, тот же поисковик по-разному будет теги обрабатывать. По такой логике большинство тегов от div ничем не отличается, можно же через css любое отображение задать.

Answer (score 3):

http://web-standards.ru/articles/i-b-em-strong-elements/

http://toster.ru/q/1653

http://devaka.ru/articles/strong-emphasis-vs-bold-italic

Comment: @ICE, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.